# Restoring a split image created by dcfldd

Tags: backup, restore, dd, disk-image

Say an image is generated by `dcfldd` using the following command:

```
dcfldd if=/dev/sourcedrive hash=md5,sha256 hashwindow=10G md5log=md5.txt \
sha256log=sha256.txthashconv=after bs=512 conv=noerror,sync split=10G \
splitformat=aa of=driveimage.dd
```

This would create a series of 10GB images named `driveimage.dd.aa`, `driveimage.dd.ab`, `driveimage.dd.ac` etc.

What would be the command to restore the split image to the source drive? I'm hoping it would be as simple as:

```
dcfldd if=driveimage.dd of=/dev/sourcedrive
```

Would `dcfldd` then automatically detect all files in the directory containing `driveimage.dd` and stitch them together again?

Answer (score 0):

You can recombine the images easily with cat, and pipe that to dcfldd to get the nice status output.

```
cat driveimage.dd.* | dcfldd of=/dev/sourcedrive
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! That makes sense and puts my mind at rest.